# mongodb like concat mysql query

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sql-like, concatenation

I have a table in Mysql where I have some D and C classes of IPs and I use this table to test if a request IP is in the database OR belongs to the C class like that:

```
select * from My_Table 
where '192.168.1.12' LIKE CONCAT(ip, '%');
```

(where 192.168.1.12 is the request IP I am testing against my table)

In my Database, if I have the ip '192.168.1' in C format, I will get a match.

I was thinking about using MongoDB and have the same information in documents where each IP (either in C or D class format) is the _id (which is indexed by default).

How can I get it to work with MongoDB if regex would work just the opposite way? (if I had the C class beforehand)

If I split every request IP into a C class to check with regex like:

```
db.my_table.find(_id: '^/split_ip/')
```

I would have to check in my application again every result by iteration and I think that wouldn't be a good solution.

So, I am wondering if you have any advice or suggestion to give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the $in operator to get all matching from a single query.

`{ _id: {$in : [/^192.0.1.1/, /^194.1.1/ ] }}`

Becuase you're using `/^` option in regex, the index will be used.

Does that help?

Comment: No problem. Pls mark as answer if this solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean its returning more than you want?  i.e. where you have a C and D you only want the C?  i.e. 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3 exist in the database. Could you give example of data you want to match? not-match? How are your ips stored?

Comment: could you not just use equals { _id: {$in : ['192.1.1.1', '193.1.3.4', '1.2.3' ] }}

Comment: Sambomartin, YES! it Worked! Thanks Again, unfortunately I can not give you a vote up as it requires 15 reputation and I am just starting here. I am doing like that: Striping the request IP to a C class, and using equals to both the request and its C class... like that: { _id: {$in : ['10.10.10', '10.10.10.6']}} , this wouldn't match 10.10.10.2 for instance, unless the C class is in the database… Cheers!