# Translate MYSQL query to mongodb using $Lookup

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongodb and I have to move my SQL Queries to mongodb now. I read the document and gained enough knowledge on writing mongodb QUeries but coming from MYSQL it will take time to get expertise on framing Mongo Queries.

I am trying to convert this query to Mongo for now using $Lookup

```
select * from orig_tbl emas
inner join  cust-tbl_after_cleanup tmclient
on emas.state = tmclient.province
and emas.cons_city = tmclient.city
where 
emas.state = 'VT' and
emas.can_match_address like concat('%',tmclient.street,'%')
and emas.can_cmp_name like concat('%',tmclient.name,'%')
and emas.can_match_address like concat('%',tmclient.house_num,'%')
and emas.can_match_address like concat('%',tmclient.postal_code,'%')
and emas.cons_city like concat('%',tmclient.city,'%')
and emas.State like concat('%',tmclient.province,'%')
group by tmclient.id,tmclient.name
```

As you can see I'm doing an inner join on multiple conditions and then doing a partial string match on number of cloumns. From the document I got to know how to do a multiple condition join but not sure how to do partial string match

**Code so far:**

```
aggregate(

    [
    { 
         '$match' : { 'name' : 'Walmart' } 
    },
    { 
        '$lookup': 
            {
  'from': 'entity_map_all_states',
  'let': { 'order_city': "$city", 'order_qty': "$province" },
           'pipeline': [
              { '$match':
                 { '$expr':
                    { '$and':
                       [
                         { '$eq': [ "$cons_city",  "$$order_city" ] },
                         { '$eq': [ "$State", "$$order_qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           'as': "stockdata"
         }
    }
    ] )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb like concat mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562076/mongodb-like-concat-mysql-query)

Comment: Instead showing mysql query. You should show some sample document the output you want with some minor explanation.

Comment: Use $regex for partial string match.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/